# How to create a regex expression to get a substring between 2 pipes

Tags: r, string, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I have a dataset that I'm trying to work with where I need to get the text between two pipe delimiters. The length of the text is variable so I can't use length to get it. This is the string:

```
ENST00000000233.10|ENSG00000004059.11|OTTHUMG000
```

I want to get the text between the first and second pipes, that being `ENSG00000004059.11`. I've tried several different regex expressions, but I can't really figure out the correct syntax. What should the correct regex expression be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex.

```r
x <- "ENST00000000233.10|ENSG00000004059.11|OTTHUMG000"
sub("^[^\\|]*\\|([^\\|]+)\\|.*$", "\\1", x)
#> [1] "ENSG00000004059.11"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Explanation:

- `^` beginning of string;
- `[^\\|]*` not the pipe character zero or more times;
- `\\|` the pipe character needs to be escaped since it's a meta-character;
- `^[^\\|]*\\|` the 3 above combined mean to match anything but the pipe character at the beginning of the string zero or more times until a pipe character is found;
- `([^\\|]+)` group match anything but the pipe character at least once;
- `\\|.*$` the second pipe plus anything until the end of the string.

Then replace the 1st (and only) group with itself, `"\\1"`, thus removing everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to get the second item after splitting the string on `|`.

```
x <- "ENST00000000233.10|ENSG00000004059.11|OTTHUMG000"

strsplit(x, "\\|")[[1]][[2]]
# strsplit(x, "[|]")[[1]][[2]]

# [1] "ENSG00000004059.11"
```

Or with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

str_split(x, "\\|") %>% map_chr(`[`, 2)

# [1] "ENSG00000004059.11"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use the regex for look ahead and look behind to extract strings that are surrounded by two "|".

The regex literally means - look one or more characters (`.+?`) behind "|" (`(?<=\\|)`) until one character before "|" (`(?=\\|)`).

```
library(stringr)

x <- "ENST00000000233.10|ENSG00000004059.11|OTTHUMG000"
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\|).+?(?=\\|)")

[1] "ENSG00000004059.11"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `\|.*\|` or in R `\\|.*\\|` since you need to escape the escape characters. (It's just escaping the first pipe followed by any character (.) repeated any number of times (*) and followed by another escaped pipe).

Then wrap in `str_sub(MyString, 2, -2)` to get rid of the pipes if you don't want them.